# Genexus 15 SD - Problema al actualizar base de datos Offline en Android

Tags: genexus

Nosotros tenemos una aplicación **Android** (disponible en Play Store) la cual fue construida por **Genexus Evolution 3 (Evo3).** Ahora hemos migrado dicha aplicación a **Genexus15 (GX15)** con éxito.

El inconveniente radica que cuando se actualiza la aplicación desde la versión realizada con Evo 3 hasta la versión realizado con GX 15 al parecer la base no se reconstruye correctamente. La actualización se efectúa correctamente, pero al querer abrir la aplicación se "crashea" debido a que quiere realizar una consulta a una tabla no existente (el típico error "No such table"). **NOTA:** Al borrar datos de la aplicación, esta si funciona. Pero no queremos dicho comportamiento con nuestro usuario final.

**Cabe recalcar:**

- En medio de la migración de Evo3 a GX15 se crearon nuevas tablas tanto en Evo 3 como en GX15.
- Hemos intentado hacer Rebuild, Create Offline Database, crear nuevas Tablas, entre otras.
- Otro punto importante a recalcar es que la base de datos si tiene algunas tablas creadas, pero aparentemente las tablas creadas entre la versión de la Play Store (hecho con Evo3) hasta las nueva versión (hecha con GX15) no son creadas correctamente.

¿Hay alguna forma de forzar que se reconstruya la base de datos en esta nueva versión (en teoría debe reconstruir todas las tablas automáticamente pero no lo hace)? También verificamos que si se ejecuta el "OnCreate" del DatabaseHelper (del FlexibleCliente) pero al parecer no quiere crear las nuevas tablas en la actualización de la aplicación.

Quedamos a la espera de cualquier ayuda disponible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La creación de la BD offline en el dispositivo ocurre cuando la estructura de la BD de la aplicación cambio.

En particular en el Flexible Client se verifica que el hash de la estructura de BD anterior es distinto al de la nueva y son la misma aplicación.

Por lo que comentas, todo esto es así en este caso. Ya que se produjeron cambios en la BD (entre Ev3 y v15) y la aplicación es la misma que estas actualizando en el Play Store.

De cualquier manera puede estar ocurriendo alguna de estas cosas:

Es probable que alguna de las 2 aplicaciones no haya generado correctamente el md5 o que no las reconozca como la misma app, el md5 de la versión anterior se guarda en las internal preferences de la app que dependen del nombre del main.

Si tienes disponible la versión anterior y la actual. Sería bueno comparar los archivos **MainApplication**.java de cada una ubicados en:

{main}\src\main\java{package}\ MainApplication.java

Estos archivos deben tener los 2 un md5 generador en el método **setReorMD5Hash**() y deben ser diferentes.
Ademas deben coincidir el identificador de la app o sea los métodos **setName**() y **setAppEntry**() deben recibir el mismo parámetro.

Si todo lo anterior está correcto, también puedes prender el **Log Level=Debug** en la propiedades del main de la app y ver que ocurre al iniciar cuando debería hacer el create database.

**Nota**: Puedes forzar el create offline database con el método resetOfflineDatabase(), pero no es la idea. Esta creación se debe hacer automáticamente en un update de la app.

Espero tus comentarios. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Te comento que he revisado ambos MainApplication: los MD5 hashes son diferentes, pero aparentemente el identificador de la app es diferente (lo que está dentro de setName(), lo del setAppEntry() si es igual). Esto es seguramente porque nuestra KB tiene 2 Main (para 2 APK) pero al pasarlo a GX 15 creamos otra KB con otro nombre y tal vez algo se perdió por ahí. ¿Existirá una forma de cambiar el identificador dentro del setName() y crees que deba optar por el resetOfflineDatabase?

Comment: Me olvidé comentarte que creamos una KB con otro nombre e importamos la vieja KB vía XPZ.

Comment: Debe ser eso entonces. Para hacer coincidir el nombre puedes modificar el template de la instalacion de Gx MainApplication.java, ubicado en: \Android\Templates\ApplicationProject\src\main\java\com\genexus\namespace . Eso te sirve como work around. Como solucion defenitiva, tendrias que creer la Kb con el mismo nombre que la original.

Comment: Te comento que el workaround ha funcionado perfectamente. Lo de cambiar el nombre de la KB lo haré en el futuro. Te agradezco la ayuda.